# About delete in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm freshman in c++.
What's the difference between "**delete a**" and "**delete b**" ? Thanks a lot!

```
    int* a = NULL ;
    int* b = new int(10) ;
    a = b;
    
    delete a;//does the space of b free?
    delete b;
```

ps：my bad！i dont mean  **delete a,b** at same time，it's actually two ways of delete memery which i wanna ask.

Another question!

How to **release** the int allocated by the expression **new int(10) in case 2**?

```
//case 1: right 
    int *a= new int(10);
    delete a;
//case 2: 
    int b = *new int(10); // how to release the int?
```

Comment: They both do the same thing since `a` and `b` point to the same object. But since you do `delete a;` first, the `int` stops existing and `delete b;` becomes an error (you can't destroy an object twice).

Comment: Because of the assignment `a = b`, `delete a` has the effect of releasing the `int` dynamically allocated by the expression `new int(10)`.    Since `a` and `b` are equal (and not null), the `delete b` has undefined behaviour (due to attempt to release the same dynamically allocated `int` more than once).

Comment: ***i dont mean delete a,b at same time，it's actually two ways of delete memery which i wanna ask.*** There is nothing different from `delete a;` and `delete b;` they are both pointers to a single integer that was dynamically allocated. The problem however is because of the `a=b;` they both point to the same location. You are not permitted to free memory more than 1 time. It's undefined behavior to do so.

Comment: There is no way to free memory in case of *new int(10);. You have already leaked it. By

Answer (score 2):

You called a single `new`, you need to a call a single `delete`. After `a = b;` you can delete either one. But you must delete only one. Deleting through either pointer will have the same effect. After the `delete` call, both variables will become invalid, pointing to freed memory.